# Keep prisma studio from production

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

I use prisma for our database and worry that prisma studio could be a security issue for production. Reading through the docs they don't seem to mention this nor do they show a way to disable it. Do you all have any suggestions on disabling prisma studio for production? I feel like the best solution would be to separate prisma studio from prisma and put prisma studio as a dev dependency, but it does not appear that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the whole `prisma` package should be installed as dev-dependency as the doc suggests :

```
npm install prisma --save-dev
```

So far, the only package I have installed as a dependency was `@prisma/client`.

Comment: That is how mine is, but I can still run npx prisma studio on production.